# Python & request : send post with id?

Tags: python, request

I would like to submit a form on a webpage.

The page has however several forms :

```
<form method="post" action="https://mywebsite.com/pageA" id="order" class="order ajaxForm">
<input type="text" class="decimal" name="value" id="fieldA" value="0" />
</label>
</form>

<form method="post" action="https://mywebsite.com/pageB" id="previousorder" class="order ajaxForm">
<input type="text" class="decimal" name="value" id="fieldB" value="0" />
</label>
</form>
```

Is there an easy way to trigger a specific form using python & request ?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to trigger a specific form using python & request ?" Yes

Comment: Are you asking how to _submit_ a form, or how to _process_ a form submission?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with some more advanced tools like [`mechanize`](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize) or [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup). The latter is actually based on `requests` internally (I assume you meant [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package by "request"). Both of these tools allow to "select a desired form" and then submit it specifying the required parameters.

For instance, submitting the `order` form with `MechanicalSoup` would look something like this:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("https://yourwebsite.com")

# Fill-in the order form
browser.select_form('#order')
browser["value"] = "100"
browser.submit_selected()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the DevTools Network tab while posting a form.
Every form will have different request url and post parameters. Generally, what you will need to do with `requests` is something like that:

```
    req = requests.post('https://mywebsite.com/pageB', 
                         data = {'fieldB':'value_you_want_to_submit'})
```

But better first investigate it with DevTools.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this: (prob need to make some modifications but it will be close to what you want this example is for login form):

install lxml

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {
"username": "<USER NAME>", 
"password": "<PASSWORD>", 
"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "<CSRF_TOKEN>"
}

sessionReq = requests.session()

login_url = "https://example.be/account/login.php"
result = sessionReq.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']/@value")))[0]

result = sessionReq.post(login_url,data = payload, headers = dict(referer = login_url)
url = 'https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview'
```

I hope this helps you :)